# Python 3.8 DJANGO GCLOUD issue

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

Strange and frustrating issue.

Have two django apps which require to be hosted on Google Cloud. The first app is currently active and being served, the second app will not give in.

The situation is as following;

Two python 3.8 django apps
Two different cloud projects with each dedicated MySQL 8.0 instances

When python manage.py runserver (app one) locally with glcoud first project activated and CLoud_sql_proxy to be listening for connections, it correctly connects to the Google MySQL instance.

(Development) D:\Development>Cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="someinstance:europe-west2:somename"=tcp:3306
2021/04/29 13:42:08 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for someinstance:europe-west2:somenam
2021/04/29 13:42:08 Ready for new connections

Now I am doing the same thing for the second app (not simultaneously), correct project activated and CLoud_sql_proxy to be listening for connections based on connection to the second Google MySQL instance.

It will not connect to the MySQL instance, instead local is being used.

if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):

is always true.

Has anyone have some tips? Troubleshooting? Maybe someone has experienced the same? Two apps work along the same lines, and cloud configuration is the same.

Setting.py

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)  # change mysqlclient version
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# Local development mode 24/04/2020
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
#     Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
#     the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/someinstance:europe-west2:somename',
            'PORT': '3306',            
            'USER': 'admin',            
            'PASSWORD': '8t09q7OG0lx1jAy2',
            'NAME': 'bscsportaltest',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Comment: `os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):` will return `None` in local as this variable does not exist in your environment by default(unless you manually added it). In that case, your app will choose **sqlite local database** as that's how you have the code. Can you please explain what's what exactly yo you expect to happen? If you expect to connect to Cloud SQL Proxy in local, then you need to have a config with `HOST = localhost` instead of the sqlite config

Comment: Take a look at: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None)` will return `None` in local as this variable does not exist in your environment by default(unless you manually added it). In that case, your app will choose sqlite local database as that's how you have the code.

If you expect to connect to Cloud SQL Proxy in local, then you need to have a config with HOST = localhost instead of the sqlite config. Something like below:

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)  # change mysqlclient version
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# Local development mode 24/04/2020
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
#     Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
#     the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/someinstance:europe-west2:somename',
            'PORT': '3306',            
            'USER': 'admin',            
            'PASSWORD': '8t09q7OG0lx1jAy2',
            'NAME': 'bscsportaltest',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) for more info.

Comment: I assumed the google cloud proxy influences this condition. So what influences the output of GAE_APPLICATION ? The fact its running within a google app engine? How does my local environment knows it is? Clearly there is something wrong there. As mentioned I have another web app running which connect locally to the google MySql Instance.

Comment: Output of GAE_APPLICATION is the fact that it is running on app engine. You can print the value on standard output and see what it is. The fact that Cloud SQL proxy is running has no effect on django detecting the GAE_APPLICATION environment variable. Also, it seems like you are a bit unsure on how to use the Cloud SQL Proxy. I would suggest you to try to run the code that I shared and also compare it with the code of the app that is already running as expected to understand what you are doing wrong.